# Hibernate Validator generic and cross-parameter constraint parameter passing

Tags: java, date, annotations, hibernate-validator

I want to check whether the value in startDate field is "before" the value endDate field.
This is my Bean class:

```
@AfterStartDate({"startOfDilation","endOfDilation"})
public class MyBean{ 
    private Date startDate,
    private Date stopDate,
    ...
}
```

The annotation gives the error "Cannot find method `value`". Do I define it right? I want to use this annotation for other bean classes too. So, that's why I don't want to use MyBean class to pass values to Annotation class.

AfterStartDate.java

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = AfterStartDateValidator.class)
public @interface AfterStartDate {
    String message() default "{AfterStartDate.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

AfterStartDateValidator.java

```
@SupportedValidationTarget(ValidationTarget.PARAMETERS)
public class AfterStartDateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<AfterStartDate,Object[]> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(AfterStartDate constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object[] value, ConstraintValidatorContext context){
        if ( value.length != 2 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Illegal method signature" );
        }

        //leave null-checking to @NotNull on individual parameters
        if ( value[0] == null || value[1] == null ) {
            return true;
        }

        if ( !( value[0] instanceof Date ) || !( value[1] instanceof Date ) ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Illegal method signature, expected two " +
                        "parameters of type Date."
            );
        }

        return ( (Date) value[0] ).before( (Date) value[1] );
       }
   }
```

Comment: Please provide stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the issue you have with your IDE is that you define a value for your annotations but you don't have a value() attribute defined in your annotation.

But this is your less pressing issue.

What you want is a class level constraints and you're using a cross parameter one hoping it will do what you want. It won't.

To do what you want to do, you need:

- to define a class level constraint (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.0#section-class-level-constraints)
- if you don't want your class level constraint to directly use your bean getters and be generic, you can define the properties as a value() of your annotation, as you did (but obviously, you need to declare a value() attribute in your annotation)
- then from the property names defined in value(), you need to use reflection to extract the values from your bean using the property names. See the tutorial here for the basics about reflection: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html